# Hide when scrolling down and appear when scrolling up

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery to hide a div when scrolling down and make it appear when it scrolling up. The first half works in that it hides when scrolling down but not when scrolling up. I think the problem is with (scrollPosition) because with scrolling up the position is irrelevant. I just need it to make the div appear with any amount of upwards scrolling.

If you wouldn't mind having a look at my code to help me replace the scrollPosition I'd be so grateful.

Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop();
if (scrollPosition >= 250) {
$('#kad-header-menu').fadeOut('slow');
}
if (scrollPosition < 250) {
$('#kad-header-menu').fadeIn('slow');
}
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code, but **.fadeIn('slow')** and **.fadeOut('slow')** does not work properly.

I use this functionality like this :

```
window.onscroll = function () { scrollFunction(); };


 function scrollFunction() {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20)
            $("#backToTop").show();
        else
            $("#backToTop").hide();
    }
```